# Is it “backward/forward” or “backwards/forwards”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can *backward* and *forward* be used interchangeably with *backwards* and *forwards*, or is there some particular situation in which one pair is consistently used over the other?

Comment: The first pair is American English; the second pair is British English.

Comment: @BillFranke That is not true.

Comment: Executive summary: AmE—Use *backward* and *forward*; *backwards* and *forwards* are uncommon, and if you use them in some parts of the country you might sound like a foreigner. BrE—Use *backward* and *forward* for adjectives; *backwards* and *forwards* for adverbs. On a ship: use *for'ard*. I've never seen *for'ards*, and *Oxford Dictionaries Online* doesn't have it either.

Comment: @PeterShor I’m pretty sure that a ***forward**-thinking attitude* in a ***backward*-gazing world** never have the *‑s* on the ends of either of them. It seems that the directional modifiers (read: adverbs) on participial adjectives are exempt from any sort of interchangeability rule or regionalism, at least as far as I have been able to uncover.

Answer (score 10):

In British English (and possibly others), *backward* and *forward* are adjectives, and *backwards/forwards* are adverbs.

A person may be backward<sup>1</sup> or forward; a car may be forward of a "Stop" line; one might move something forward (that is, to a position which is forward of its current position). However, when describing that movement itself, it's *forwards*.

Related question: [Meaning of "backwards"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69049/meaning-of-backwards?rq=1)

<sup>1</sup> Using *backward* to describe some developmental abnormality is frowned upon and not recommended. In fact, describing someone as *forward* is rather dated, too.

Comment: In AmE, we use them interchangeably. (Although *backwards* and *forwards* are less common.)

Comment: @PeterShor So you would say that a car is forwards of a Stop line? Or simply use *forward* as the adverbial form?

Comment: Given that English adverbs are usually impossible to distinguish from English adjectives in actual constructions (how many ELU questions and answers suggest that something is or isn't an adverb, and speculate on why or why not?), I suspect that the rule quoted may be more honored in the breach than the observance  throughout the UK. Is there a study of UK usage? Beyond "guides", I mean -- actual linguistic surveys with data and statistics.

Comment: In the United States, the forms are used as @PeterShor describes. Their usage here is similar to that of [_toward(s)_ and _beside(s)_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/besides.html).

Comment: **“-ward(s):** The two forms are so nearly synonymous…choice between them is mostly determined by some notion of euphony in the particular context; some persons, apparently, have a fixed preference for the one or the other form. Sometimes, however, the difference in the form of the suffix corresponds to a difference in the shade of meaning conveyed, though ***it would not be possible to give any general rule that would be universally accepted***. … Hence -wards seems to have an air of precision…avoided in poetical use. There appears to be no appreciable difference…between…toward and towards;…”

Comment: @tchrist Your reference (what is it?) seems to state (I'm unsure because of the ellipsis) that _-wards_ is avoided in poetical use. If that is what it says, I am startled to see it, because a contrary example, one of the most famous lines in all of modern poetry, instantly leapt to mind: "And what rough beast, its hour come round at last, Slouches towards Bethlehem to be born?" (from _The Second Coming_, by Yeats) Only one instance, but an awfully powerful one. I can't swear to this, having not yet researched it, but I feel in my bones that other examples would be fairly easy to come by.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Yeah, I’m not completely sure of how much it actually tends to be avoided in poetic use, nor by whom. I am sure, however, that there is no universally accepted rule here.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross In AmE, we would not typically use either forward or forwards in that context. (I'm not saying we never do, merely that it's not common.) AmE would tend toward/towards (either works) "over the stop line," or "ahead of the stop line," or "past the stop line," depending on the context. If "forward/forwards" is indeed chosen, then yes, the form absent the "s" (and requiring an attendant "of") would be much preferred.

Comment: @tchrist Agreed. And what is the reference?

Comment: What I am a little surprised and disappointed about is that I specifically said "British English", and all the commenters have been American. And I suspect the downvoter is too.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Oh,that was the OED. One can—and should—look up the detailed definitions, notes, and citations for all of *-ward(s), backward(s), forward(s), toward(s)* there, but as ProfL points out, the proof of the pudding is in the eating, so until you carefully examine actual corpus instances and aggregate data, probably along several different axes, you will not be able to say much about what really is or is not used in the wild—let alone by whom. At the end of day, I expect OED’s ***“it would not be possible to give any general rule that would be universally accepted”*** still applies.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross Gosh, SJC, we're not all trolls; I'm sorry you think the downvoter would likely be from this side of the pond. I take your point, however, that the Brits don't seem to be weighing in. My above comment to you, with specific reference to AmE, however, was not ignoring your original answer; it was responding to your question to PeterShor, and you were asking about American usage. As for your original answer here, I found it excellent, and upvoted it.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross Do clocks go *backwards* and *forwards* or *backward* and *forward*?